# Finding this error when trying to install Tensorflow. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow. This is the error that is displayed. Its also same for trying to install scikit. Seems like there is a python directory that is protected by the system and the installer is unable to remove it. 
[Here is a Screenshot of terminal log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhIi2.png)

Comment: please paste error in the SO post

Comment: Operation not permitted, try to execute the command with sudo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a better answer it's necessary to tell us more about your method of installation and the steps you have passed to get this error.
But based on what I can see on your screenshot you can run the installation command with `sudo your_installation_command`